# Android Media Player with support of MPEG-DASH

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I'm looking for an open-source media player or API for Android that can support MPEG-DASH and its amendments such as the [Spatial Relation Description (SRD)](http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-dash/media-presentation-description-and-segment-formats/text-isoiec-23009-12014-dam-2) feature for tiled videos. Any suggestions?

I thought the `mediaplayer` API of Android supports DASH, but apparently it does not. They advocate for a player called ExoPlayer (http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) that supports DASH, smooth Streaming, and such. I was wondering if it supports all features of DASH such as SRD?

How about HEVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently Exoplayer doesnot support SRD. reference : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1569

For HVEC, I think yes. reference : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/605

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [dash-srd.js](https://github.com/tnomedialab/dash-srd.js), which is the player issued by medialab.

It is based on dash.js and also supports SRD.